# How to clear a sequence of audio with timeouts in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set 4 timeout for audios in my application and I need to stop the audios after user click. The macro function is working correctly, however the clearTimout does not stop the sound. Anyone knows how to clear it?

```
export function handlePlay(audio) {
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  return audio.play();
}

export function handleConversation(clear) {
  const timer1 = () => setTimeout(() => {
    handlePlay(conversation[Math.floor(Math.random() * conversation.length)]);
  }, TIME1);

  const timer2 = () => setTimeout(() => {
    handlePlay(conversation[Math.floor(Math.random() * conversation.length)]);
  }, TIME2);

  const timer3 = () => setTimeout(() => {
    handlePlay(conversation[Math.floor(Math.random() * conversation.length)]);
  }, TIME3);

  const timer4 = () => setTimeout(() => {
    handlePlay(conversation[Math.floor(Math.random() * conversation.length)]);
  }, TIME4);

  if (clear) {
    console.log('enter clear');
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer1);
      clearTimeout(timer2);
      clearTimeout(timer3);
      clearTimeout(timer4);
    };
  }
  timer1();
  timer2();
  timer3();
  timer4();
}
```

Comment: clearTimeout will just cancel the callback of the timeout but if the sound has begun playing you should keep track of the channel and explicitely call stop() on it.

Comment: @Peterrabbit I didnt find a way to call stop() once the audio is inside the timeout and after fired have no control. How can I do it?

Comment: By the way, you probably don't want to use `setTimeout()` to handle your audio playback timing.  They're not  meant to be accurate, and depending on the browser's visibility state, you may end up with all your audio playing simultaneously.  Use the Web Audio API and playback your samples that way.

Answer (score 0):

after clearTimeouts call this code

```html
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a suggestion of what you could do.

I guess this could be improved further regarding how this handleConversation function is used, I didn't really get the whole idea and there is still some inconsistencies...

```js
 function createAudio(track) {
   track.audio = conversation[Math.floor(Math.random() * conversation.length)];
 }

 export class Track {
   constructor(time) {
     this.time = time;
     this.timeoutid = 0;
     this.audio = new Audio();
   }

   timer() {
     this.timeoutid = setTimeout(() => {
       createAudio(this);
       handlePlay(this.audio);
     }, TIME1);
   }

   play() {
     this.audio.currentTime = 0;
     this.audio.play();
   }

   stop() {
     this.audio.pause();
     this.audio.currentTime = 0;
     clearTimeout(this.timeoutid)
   }
 }

 export function handleConversation(clear) {
   const track1 = new Track(TIME1);
   const track2 = new Track(TIME2);
   const track3 = new Track(TIME3);
   const track4 = new Track(TIME4);

   // this part actually doesn't make a lot of sense, since all tracks will be recreated each time the function is called.
   // I don't really understand how this is used. 
   // I imagine the tracks should more likey be stored outside the function in a persistent object.
   // I will modify my answer if you provide more details about how you use handleConversation
   if (clear) {
     console.log('enter clear');
     return () => {
       [track1, track2, track3, track4].forEach(track => {
         track.stop()
       });
     };
   }

   [track1, track2, track3, track4].forEach(track => {
     track.timer()
   });
 }
```